# Why am I getting NoMethod error when trying to make form with nested routing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I'm using rails3.
When loading new action in nested routing, I get NoMethod Error.

> undefined method `community_community_topics_path' for #<#:0x0000000a067ef8>

How can I fix this??

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for ([@community, @community_topic]), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>

  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :title, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_field :title, :class => 'text_field' %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
    <%= f.label :body, :class => 'control-label' %>
    <div class="controls">
      <%= f.text_area :body, :class => 'text_area' %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                community_topics_path, :class => 'btn' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
    resources :community_topics, :path => "topic", :as => :'topic'
end
```

**rake routes | grep community_topics**

```
   community_topic_index GET    /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#index
                         POST   /shop/:community_id/topic(.:format)          community_topics#create
     new_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/new(.:format)      community_topics#new
    edit_community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id/edit(.:format) community_topics#edit
         community_topic GET    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#show
                         PUT    /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#update
                         DELETE /shop/:community_id/topic/:id(.:format)      community_topics#destroy
```

Comment: What `rake routes` tells you?

Comment: @Ernest I updated my Question. Please check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the plural form of "topic" in your routes file:

```
resources :communities, :path => "shop", do
  resources :community_topics, :path => "topics", :as => :'topics'
end
```

Do that, and you'll see `rake routes` will change the first route from `community_topic_index` to `community_topics`, letting you use `community_topics_path`

Note: you may also want to use "shops" instead of "shop", that way your URLs will be formatted consistent to how Rails usually does it: `http://example.com/shops`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! What if I dont want shops for url like example.com/shop/123/topics/? should I just make the deepest hierarhy of nested routing plural? or all of them?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to keep shop singular, only change the nested resource.

Comment: do you mean that the nested resource = topics here?

Comment: Yes... leave "shop" singular, but "topics" plural. Or, you can leave topics singular and use the other answer (manually specifying the community_topic_index_url path)

Answer (score 1):

You can specify your url manually.  Just pass it to the url param whatever route you want for the form to go to from rake routes.  It looks like from your routes file that community_topic_index_url is your post action.

```
<%= form_for :community_topic, url: community_topic_index_url, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I made my routing setup singular.  Is this supposed to be abnormal? It always has to be plural?

Comment: Convention is to be plural so you might want to make that change as well.

Comment: Thanks. what about path? it still can be singular? or both :as and :path should be plural?